# ajax call must get response from method in ajax.php?

Tags: php, ajax

This is my ajax call.

```
   $(document).on('click','#Quote_create_value',function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : '../../../protected/config/ajax.php',
            success : function(response){
                $("#Quote_template_value").html(response);
            }
        });
   });
```

I have many methods in ajax.php. Each and every method throws some response.

```
    <?php
      function respose()
      {
        $query = "select * from quote where template IS NOT NULL";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $con);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['template'].'">' . $row['template'] . '</option>';
        }

        $query1 = "select * from template";
        $data = mysql_query($query1,$con);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
            echo json_encode($row);
        }
      }

      function result()
      {
      }

    ?>
```

But i want to get response from one method [ie. from response()].

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could include a selector in the ajax request data. Like this for example:

```
   $(document).on('click','#Quote_create_value',function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : '../../../protected/config/ajax.php',
            data: "function=result",
            success : function(response){
                $("#Quote_template_value").html(response);
            }
        });
   });
```

Then in your PHP code, a simple if-statement will check which one to output.

```
if(isset($_GET['function'])) {
    if($_GET['result'] == 'result') {
        // do result stuff
    } elseif($_GET['function'] == 'response') {
        // do response stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass value of variable through ajax call? Like $(document).on('click','#Quote_create_value',function(){ 
 $template = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : '../../../protected/config/ajax.php',
            data: "function=result($template)",
            success : function(response){
                $("#Quote_template_value").html(response);
            }
        });
   });

Comment: Yes. If you want to use a value from a php variable I'd first declare it as a JS-variable as such `var variable = <?php echo json_encode($variable); ?>;`. Then you can use it like this: `data: "function=result&value=variable"`. Also, if my answer solved your questions I'd appreciate if you marked it as the correct answer :-) Thanks.

Comment: I am not getting. value is not passing.

Comment: Sorry, it's suppose to be `data: "function=result&value=" + variable`.